# Fortify SCA/SSC Report for IA?

Tags: static-analysis, fortify

I'm a developer working on a mid-size c# application and am using the Fortify Secure coding plugin for Visual Studio 2010 to do static code analysis on a regular basis.  We're nearing the end of this development cycle and I was asked to provide a vulnerability report to IA.

I've not had to do submit before, and IA doesn't appear to be familiar with the Fortify reports.  My plan is to generate 2 or 3 reports and submit to IA so they can decide which is most appropriate for their use.  I'm not quite certain which report(s), (with which options) would be appropriate for submission to IA.  I also have access to generate reports from Audit Workbench and SSC.

So the question is, which Fortify report (with which configs) does your organization provide to your IA shop?  Or more generically, what type of Static Analysis vulnerability information do you provide to IA?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might need to define what IA means for your organization

Comment: Good point. IA is the group that authorizes applications for deployment on our network.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that "IA" stands for "Information Assurance". When you deal with infosec types, you need to be precise in language, since they need to be. I'm transitioning from being a developer to somewhat infosec, so it has been a challenge for me, too.

The IA team has asked you for a vulnerability report, which would be the output of penetration testing. The output of a penetration test would include weaknesses that are proven to be exploitable, whereas a static security assessment from static analysis would include weaknesses in the code that are not necessarily exploitable. There are also limits to the types of issues that static analysis can find, so it is in no way a replacement for dynamic assessments or penetration testing.

Many companies require results of multiple types of analysis as part of their requirement to approve an application. Manual penetration testing is sometimes done, but frequently a scanner such as WebInspect or AppScan is used to scan an application in place of manual pen testing. When results from a web app scanner are combined with static analysis results, it covers both potential weaknesses in code as well as typical vulnerabilities in a deployed application (when running in an environment like your production environment).

You should work with your IA team to determine the process of vetting an application for deployment to production, as well as who is responsible for which steps in the process. You will likely need to schedule them to conduct pen testing on your application in your QA or functional testing environment.

As for report, if they want the results of your static analysis, I'd look at generating a report that's less than 20 pages for them to start, which includes the most prevalent issues in web applications, assuming you're writing a web application. I'm partial to the CWE/SANS Top 25 2010 report in SSC, without the "Detailed Report" option.

Answer (score 0):

I would generate the FPR with SCA, extract the FPR file (unzip), open the audit.fvdl, parse the Vulnerabilities XML tag to create a list of Issues and upload them to the reporting software. If some translations are needed, it can be done during the upload. You can check how [Sonar plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Fortify+Plugin) does something like this.